# Enabling Compliance BCC Emails Programmatically using sfdx

Tags: salesforcedx

Here's a reference on how to perform this manually
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_compliancebcc.htm&type=5

I would like to set this programmatically using sfdx. Should I deploy apex code? Can I deploy via metadata api? Or is it an object where I can have data upserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `EmailAdministrationSettings` [metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_emailadministrationsettings.htm) type and deploy via sfdx.

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -m "Settings:EmailAdministration"
```

You will need a source file `EmailAdministrationSettings.settings`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <EmailAdministrationSettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
            <enableComplianceBcc>true</enableComplianceBcc>
  </EmailAdministrationSettings>
```

**Update**

There is no metadata support to set up the actual email addresses. You will need to automate via selenium or a [puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) script

Comment: Hi Mohith, the EmailAdministrationSettings gives option to enable it. How do I specify the email address?

Comment: I updated my answer. Check it out!!